# How is this practical and very old scene shot?

Tags: effects, sh-the-octopus

Saw a Reddit post talking about this scene from 1937's [Sh! The Octopus](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0029541/):

It is 82 years old and a great practical effect. How was it shot, though?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

I thought this was going to be a long and difficult investigation...

However, the answer was right there on IMDB, in the [Trivia section](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0029541/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv)

> The transformation scene was done in much the same way the beginning
>   part of the transformation was done on [Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde (1931)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0022835).
>   The actress was made up in exaggerated highlights and shadows
>   (including her teeth) using a single color shade of makeup. When
>   filmed through a filter the same shade as the makeup, it's invisible
>   to the camera. Take the filter away and the makeup suddenly becomes
>   visible. Besides a filter, the makeup can also be hidden by
>   similar-colored light. This type of trick was only possible on
>   black-and-white film.

Very clever indeed.

The seemingly 'slow' transformation is then probably achieved using a graduated filter [filter at one end, clear at the other], larger than the lens, which can be pulled relatively slowly in front, to achieve the apparent change.

Comment: Invented by Karl Struss - also see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yM1S7sXw-wE

Comment: Ah, the graduated filter is brilliant!

Comment: red make-up with a red filter, I've heard https://www.reddit.com/r/creepy/comments/c46be2/practical_effects_from_an_80_year_old_film/erwzzja?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x